# DVI portion of video card stopped working after re-installing XP

Tags: video, drivers, amd-radeon

After a clean install of XP, the DVI side of my video card only works with a DVI to VGA adapter (VGA cable now has to be used on this monitor in question).

This monitor Worked fine before with a DVI cable.  XP installed a Radeon 9200 series driver.  I downloaded a more specific Radeon 9250 driver, but it did not help.  I would just use the adapter, but the quality of this monitor is lower than that of my primary monitor.

Comment: How have you established it is the DVI on the graphics card rather than the DVI on the monitor or the DVI cable?  Seems strange that a DVI->VGA adapter would work (where it takes a DVI signal and converts it successfully) and yet the DVI signal doesn't work without conversion.

Comment: For what it's worth the DVI->VGA adapter doesn't do any conversions - it uses the analog output pins that are part of the DVI connector to begin with (DVI connectors usually output both digital and analog signals).

Comment: @user55325 Oh yeah DVI-I, I forgot about this, it is most likely that this is what is being used.  So we don't know that any digital signal is being produced from the card.